# Trying to pull value from Data Layer in Google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Trying to pull "hash" value for 'Scramble_ip' event. Any idea how this can be done? I can't use ([n]) event numbers because the number of events varies from page to page. Can I call the event by name? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that technically you've allowed your value to be overwritten by a different event's value that is using `hash` key too. Stop giving simple/repetitive names yo your properties and you will be good.

To fix this your best action would be to change the name of the hash, then make a DL variable in GTM for the new name and then use that.

If you can't change the name of the variable, then you still can hack around it with either:

1. a piece of JS that iterates through your DL and pulls your value. So the core of it would be something like:

```js
function(){
  return dataLayer.find(function(obj){return obj.event==="Scramble_IP"}).hash;
}
```

2. solve it via a mostly UI set up by making a Scramble_IP Data Layer Event trigger and have custom HTML tag using it that would just save the value of your dataLayer Value variable 'hash' to a cookie or a different variable, or a local JS variable, or to another DL variable. As you see fit really.

Comment: Hi @BNazaruk, could you possibly share example code for how to store the hash as a different variable + how to retrieve it subsequently? Facing same issue as OP where I have multiple events and need to save the hashes of each event. Thanks!

Comment: Well, ideally, you would only need "this" event's hash, which is not the author's case. In case you only need "this" event's case, you don't need code to retrieve it. You just make a dataLayer variable and the value will be there on every event. Now, usually the front-end team sends us those dataLayer pushes, so they would add a hash as per your requirements. Normally, we can generate hashes too. In the author's case, it's not even a hash, it's just a simple base64 encoded string. base64 is comfy and quick in JS thanks to atob() and btoa(). Real hash would take more code.